# Tryinng to get CAELinux to boot

Tags: linux

I believe that CAELinux has successfully installed on a SD card on a laptop. When I rebooted what I am left with is a GRUB prompt. If I enter the chainloader command it expects things like the device name of the linux image. I really want to know if CAELinux has installed and if it runs OK. Then I shall learn more about GRUB because I have another distribution that I am interested in.

How can I simply start CAELinux from the GRUB prompt?

Comment: How's this apply to 3D printing?

Comment: CAELinux is a distrubution centered around 3D modelling and printing. I have tried posting on their forums with these questions regarding booting after installation with no reply. I know that it is off topic but this is the closest type of group I can find on the stackexchange to what I want to know.

Comment: Have you tried their forum (https://www.caelinux.com/CMS3/index.php/forum)? Seems a more appropriate place to ask.

Comment: Yes I have and get no response

Comment: Go try the Unix and Linux, they may be better prepared to help on this matter. But I would imagine they suggest what I am going to suggest. Use a more common distro like Ubuntu and install the packages on that, you will find more support that way. Otherwise my guess is that the device of the sd-card reader does not match what grub is expecting and it can't find the kernel because of that.

Comment: It is OK, I figured it out. Thanks for the help nonetheless.

Answer (score 2):

Per the [Getting Started page](http://caelinux.com/downloads/stable/2018/GettingStarted.html),

> As CAELinux is a customized Xubuntu 16.04 distribution, the installation instructions (and then administration) for Xubuntu/Ubuntu  all apply to CAELinux.
>   For more instructions on how to install CAELinux on hard drive, please follow the Ubuntu instructions here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/GraphicalInstall

Based on the information provided above, I think this question is off-topic for this site, and should be migrated to either Unix & Linux, or Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: OK it may be off topic, but I still think it is worth considering that this distro is designed for 3D modelling and printing.